# Configurable Product Price field show only readonly in M2.3 admin panel

Tags: configurable-product, price, magento2.3.0

[image]I am facing Catalog Price field not Editable. it shows only **read-only.**

Under **Catalog=>Products**

Show all Products Grid Section price are shown.
But edit specific product details field, not able to see the actual price.
Its Shows **0.00 price** with read-only type.

I am also applying few Commands on my store.

**bin/magento indexer:reindex**

**bin/magento setup:upgrade**

**bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy**

Kindly Guide me this type of issue.

I have also attached Screenshot of my webshop products field.

Comment: I think you are new in magento 2 because if you are creating configurable product it will not show price. it will take price from it's child products.

Comment: @RonakChauhan, I know price shows only simple product of configurable.
In my case child product price issue .I have also shared image.
kindly look this.